# token jwt work with spring boot but with angular there are error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

whene i try to use jwt in spring boot it work 
[connecting and setting the token with spring boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jU5y.png)
[it works this is the token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU2Gi.png)

[whene i want to work with angular there is a problem
at first whene i connect (login) he create the token and he connect correctly login successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52tF3.png)
[he create the token ][4]

[whene i navigate to another page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqHTy.png) 
[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp3UT.png) 
i think there is no problem in spring boot and i dont know what is the problem in angular

this is my routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { BoardUserComponent } from './board-user/board-user.component';
import { BoardModeratorComponent } from './board-moderator/board-moderator.component';
import { BoardAdminComponent } from './board-admin/board-admin.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: 'user', component: BoardUserComponent },
  { path: 'mod', component: BoardModeratorComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: BoardAdminComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

this is my authentication service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const AUTH_API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(credentials): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signin', {
      username: credentials.username,
      password: credentials.password
    }, httpOptions);
  }

  register(user): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(AUTH_API + 'signup', {
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    }, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

my tokenstorageservice

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const TOKEN_KEY = 'auth-token';
const USER_KEY = 'auth-user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenStorageService {

  constructor() {
  }

  signOut() {
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
  }

  public saveToken(token: string) {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, token);
  }

  public getToken(): string {
    return sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
  }

  public saveUser(user) {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  public getUser() {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(USER_KEY));
  }
}
```

user service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/test/';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPublicContent(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + 'all', { responseType: 'text' });
  }

  getUserBoard(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + 'user', { responseType: 'text' });
  }

  getModeratorBoard(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + 'mod', { responseType: 'text' });
  }

  getAdminBoard(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + 'admin', { responseType: 'text' });
  }
}
```

my AuthInterceptor

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import {TokenStorageService} from '../auth/token-storage.service';

const TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private token: TokenStorageService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    let authReq = req;
    const token = this.token.getToken();
    if (token != null) {
      authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token) });
    }
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}

export const authInterceptorProviders = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
];
```

login component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../auth/auth.service';
import {TokenStorageService} from '../auth/token-storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  form: any = {};
  isLoggedIn = false;
  isLoginFailed = false;
  errorMessage = '';
  roles: string[] = [];

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.tokenStorage.getToken()) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getUser().roles;
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.authService.login(this.form).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.tokenStorage.saveToken(data.accessToken);
        this.tokenStorage.saveUser(data);

        this.isLoginFailed = false;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getUser().roles;
        this.reloadPage();
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
        this.isLoginFailed = true;
      }
    );
  }

  reloadPage() {
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show us your Angular routing code and any authentication service you have.

Comment: i edit my question so please help me

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show the BoardUserComponent js code as well? I assume that you check if the user is logged in inside it and you made a type somewhere, so in this case do not do this. You should use guards.
Make a guard file like this and check if the user is logged in and then you must return a boolean.

**user.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '@services/auth/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private _AuthService: AuthService,
    private _Router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate() {
    if(this._AuthService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this._Router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

After that you can import it inside the routing file and write the path like this.

```
{
  path: 'user',
  canActivate: [UserGuard],
  component: BoardUserComponent
},
```

Comment: `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../_service/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-board-user',
  templateUrl: './board-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./board-user.component.css']
})
export class BoardUserComponent implements OnInit {
  content = '';

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUserBoard().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.content = data;
      },
      err => {
        this.content = JSON.parse(err.error).message;
      }
    );
  }
}
`

Comment: i dont have isloggedin like a methode

Comment: i check the solution of UserGuard and im redirected ['/auth/login]